# Case Statement Performance (is it possible to reference another case statement from within another one?)

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, case

I have a question about sub-queries and case statements

**I have two case statements in the same query:**

- One has a sub-query that is used to determine if a column has a match.
- I'd like the other to check if theres a match [among other checks], then tag a value.
- However, t-SQL will not let me reference my first field (generated from the case statement) within my second case statement.
- This forces me to add the subquery into my second case statement and do away with the first case statement
- When I do this, my query goes from 13 seconds to 2.5 minutes
- When I remove the subquery altogether from my query, it takes 8 seconds to run

**Question 1:** Can case-statement-generated fields be referenced in subsequent case statements in the same query?

**Question 2:** Why does my query take only 5 seconds longer when I have the subquery in an isolated case statement but 2 minutes longer when that subquery is in a case statement that has 4-5 other checks?

**1st Case Statement**

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT xxx.xxx from xxx) THEN 'Y' 
     END AS "Match_Ind",
```

**Second Case Statement**

```
CASE WHEN condition 1 = true THEN 'cond1'
    WHEN condition 2 = true THEN 'cond2'
    WHEN Match_Ind = 'Y' THEN 'matched'
    END AS "Match Detail"
```

Comment: can you post your full query? you might not even need that `SELECT` in a `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider posting your full query but if you want to reference the result of the first `CASE` inside of another `CASE` statement, then you can wrap it in a `SELECT` similar to this:

```
select 
    CASE 
        WHEN condition 1 = true THEN 'cond1'
        WHEN condition 2 = true THEN 'cond2'
        WHEN Match_Ind = 'Y' THEN 'matched'
    END AS Match Detail
from 
(
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN conditionHere -- (SELECT xxx.xxx from xxx)
        THEN 'Y' 
        END AS Match_Ind,
        othercols
    from yourtable
) x
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Placing the subquery in the FROM clause did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along the lines of:

```
select case Bar1 ... end as Bar2, ...
  from ( select case Foo1 ... end as Bar1, ... from ... )
```

It can be `JOIN`ed with other tables as needed.